# Selenium findElement(s) issues when search for anchor tag

Tags: java, html, selenium

I have a few nav bar items that I am trying to find with `driver.findElement(by.id("menu-news-menu-item"))` and `driver.findElements(by.id("menu-news-menu-item"))`. It can't find them for some reason. I have verified that the id is correct on the site but it still can't be found. I know there are other ways to get to the info, but it is my understanding that using the id is the best way to go about finding elements. Below I have included an HTML snippet of what I am trying to search for. If I need to provide any more information please let me know.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <li>
    <a id="menu-news-menu-item" href="/novus/news">News</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: There are several reasons why this could fail. Do you get an `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: Please include the error and your code attempt

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but when I went to run so I could grab the error message, it worked correctly with `driver.findElement(by.id("menu-news-menu-item"))`. Thank you for the quick replies though. I was getting a `NoSuchElementException` with findElement. I wondering if I just needed to add more time for the page to load.

Comment: please paste the whole code snippet so that we can help. Otherwise we are just fishing in the dark

Comment: find by id is not always the best way to go. need html of the whole page.

Comment: @YuZhang if you have an ID and your page is HTML compliant (IDs are unique on the page) then the ID is *always* the best way to go. When wouldn't it be? ... and you don't need the HTML of the whole page.

Comment: @JeffC, in my case, developers are prone to change elements' IDs without telling testers, that is the reason why I said that. But in theory, provided IDs are unique and consistent, they will be the best option to go for. If we do not have the whole HTML page, how do we know there is no duplicate elements?

Comment: @YuZhang then shame on your devs. They shouldn't be changing IDs without a good reason, especially if automation relies on them. No one on SO should be posting the whole HTML page. The OP on any question should be responsible for taking the suggestions we make and applying them to their own site. They only need to post the relevant HTML. Sometimes what is relevant is a learning process for them but that's what we're here for... to educate others.

Comment: @JeffC, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your HTML I see one potential problem. There may be more.

The top level `DIV` you posted has a class `navbar-collapse collapse`. That indicates to me that that `DIV` is collapsible and is currently collapsed which means that any of its children will be hidden. Selenium was designed to allow the user to only interact with visible elements. This means that if you search for your `A` tag by ID and it's a child of the `DIV` that is currently collapsed, Selenium won't find it. What you need to do before you search for the A tag is to unhide it. I don't know for sure how to do this but it probably involves clicking the collapsible `DIV`.

With this info, try to figure the rest out on your own. You should be able to investigate the page HTML, try some code, and see what happens. If it doesn't work and you get stuck. Come back and post some more of the surrounding HTML, the code you tried, and the result (error messages, etc.) and we'll try to help you more.